# 3 Lines of code to 1 line

Tags: c#

Consider the following lines of code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new node and enqueue it in the second queue.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="n1"></param>
/// <param name="n2"></param>
private void makeNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right)
{
    // I bet this can be a oneliner!
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
    n.Insert(left, right);
    this._q2.Enqueue(n);
}
```

As you can read my comment, I want to make a oneliner for this.

Does anyone has an idea?
Yes, I googled, but this is way to specific...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I am fully aware that these kind of things really reduces readability and is not good practice! However the idea behind this question is to see if there is a way to reduce this to one line, which might have led me to a new trick in C#. That is the main reason behind this question. Also this question should have been asked on CodeReview instead of SO, which I am aware of at this moment.

Also I am unable to delete this question so I have added some clarification in response to all the great comments I received. :)

Comment: `TreeNode n = new TreeNode(); n.Insert(left, right); this._q2.Enqueue(n);` is a one liner.

Comment: @aglasser Well-played, sir.

Comment: Why is one-line-ness so important?

Comment: It is faster, @BenN. Everyone knows that newlines cause a slowdown in execution speed.

Comment: @aglasser: and all those extra tabs/spaces for indenting. Just totally murder on performance. Maybe Intel really should update the x86 line to be capable to running properly formatted code.

Comment: At an abstract level, `makeNode` *is* the one liner. It's the one thing other consumers need to know about, the rest of it is irrelevant detail. Focus your efforts on relevancy.

Comment: That said, if it interests you, check if TreeNode has a constructor accepting the pair or if there's a factory method of some sort.

Comment: Readability should always be a key factor in writing code. An important question is to ask if making a one liner would be clearer or easier to read or not? Specifically *why* do you want to make this a one-liner?

Comment: I don't see why this question is getting down-voted. Who cares if the premise is pointless. He's obviously interested in the intellectual aspect of it rather than the best practice. Surely all of you down voters have stared at your perfectly good code at some point and attempted to refactor it into less lines. Cut him some slack for asking for help with this. It isn't a "good" question, so I don't think it should ever get above 0, but I don't see downvotes being warranted either. That being said, I had to upvote aglasser's comment b/c it's awesome.

Comment: @TTT, "the premise" being "pointless" is one of the best reasons to vote something down. Hover over the down button and check the tooltip text. This question is not useful, will never help anyone, and quite frankly could be researched and solved using documentation around `TreeNode` without ever consulting Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TTT Do I need all the lines, is a good question. Should all these lines be here, good question. Can I fit all this on one line, no. At best a waste of time, at worse make your code incomprehensible, for no reason whatsoever

Comment: @AnthonyPegram and Tony, Ok. You win. The "Not useful" aspect of the downvote does apply. Is there a forum for discussing intellectual aspects of C# code that are "pointless"? Years ago it used to be SO, but many highly rated questions on SO from 2010 or earlier would have to be downvoted by today's rules.

Comment: To give the benefit of the doubt (for @ttt), maybe by getting this code down to one line the OP believes they can actually get rid of the method completely and just use the one-liner. I don't know the context completely so I guess I shouldn't downvote this.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I'm making a Huffman encoder for fun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already have a one-liner:

```
makeNode(left, right);
```

Comment: Yes, I did this.makeNode(this._q2.Dequeue(), this._q2.Dequeue());
However I am interested in a way to write that as a oneliner, of course readability is important but I am just curious if it is possible.

Comment: What he is saying is that the call to the function happens on one line, so what difference does the implementation of the function make? Is there some reasoning behind your desire to have everything happen on one line?

Comment: Squishing separate operations into one line for no good reason will not help readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void makeNode(TreeNode left, TreeNode right)
{
    this._q2.Enqueue(newNodeHelper(left, right)); // Zing!
}

private TreeNode newNodeHelper(TreeNode left, TreeNode right)
{
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
    n.Insert(left, right);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I already did create a newNodeHelper principle with the creation of the makeNode() method.

Comment: Your helper needs a helper, needs a helper...

Comment: @Lars this answer is given in irony. Your question has no correct answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus I just wanted to know if it was possible, but it isn't, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```
this._q2.Enqueue(new TreeNode().Insert(left, right));
```

But it is always better to have it in different lines, readability is important

Comment: That will only work if `TreeNode.Insert()` returns the original `TreeNode`.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Put `backticks` around your code to format it properly :)

Comment: Yes, I know readability is important but I am just curious if it possible to write this as a oneliner...